# Landcover GeoTIFF to MBTiles with gdal_polygonize and Tippecanoe

Tags: python, gdal, mbtiles, tippecanoe

I am downloading `GeoTIFF` files from https://livingatlas.arcgis.com/landcoverexplorer and would ultimately like to turn that data into vector MBTiles files.

My process so far:

- Download GeoTIFF
- Use `gdal_polygonize` to create a geoJSON file.
- Use `tippecanoe` to create the `mbtiles` file.

Example:

`tippecanoe -o test2.mbtiles -Z2 -z13 -rg --simplification=10 --simplify-only-low-zooms -aN -s EPSG:3857 test.geojson`

My issue is the parameters needed for `tippecaoe` can be confusing. Does anyone have experience using this dataset and converting in the way I described?

Is there a better way to do what I am wanting?